# Angular Universal, SSR not working when navigating through application

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am not quite sure if this is a bug or not. What i want to achieve is that the whole project should always get server side rendered so i do not expose my API calls. What i have so far is an interceptor with transfer state thus all data from calls done in the server are passed through the browser so it does not repeat any calls.

The problem that i have is that after initial serverside rendering, when navigating through the page (through components and modules), rendering is being done inside browser and not server sided.

Is angular universal supposed to work like this or do i have something wrong in my code. If it supposed to be this then is there a way to avoid exposing my API calls to browser?

My routings (app-routing.module):

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
    }
    ]
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
       RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false, 
       initialNavigation: 'enabled' })
     ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
    })

    export class AppRoutingModule {

    }
```

Expected output is to server side all pages after initial SSRing.
Current behaviour is browser side rendering after initial SSRing.

Comment: That's how angular works. Why do you want to hide you API calls?

Comment: mostly for security, so we can keep as much as possible inside corporation's network (so we don't want to expose them)

Comment: Well, you can't really do that when using a SPA JS framework like angular